# Left Ctrl+space keyboard shortcut not working windos 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10-v1803

I cannot able to use <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> keyboard shortcut combination anywhere, but <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> works fine.

I am using **Asus ROG GL552VW**, **windows 10 Home Single Language Version 10.0.18363**.

1. In eclipse and microsoft vscode tools, this shortcut combo is for content assist. <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is not working but <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> works.
2. In windows file explorer also, it behaves the same way, <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is not working but <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> works.

<kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and all the other shortcuts works fine.

I tried many things including uninstalling keyboard drivers. But nothing works also I cannot pin point the root cause for this.

Please provide some suggestions to overcome this annoying problem.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Let me confirm on this

Comment: Yes @harrymc the same problem present in safe mode also

Comment: What do you expect Left-Ctrl+Space to do?

Comment: The same thing which right ctrl+ space does for eg. From file explorer, Multiple selection of random files in a folder

Comment: Doesn't do that here.

Comment: Same here, nothing...

Comment: @JasonXA apparently after many struggles, I found out it is a hardware issue. For my scenario, I had it working intermittently and goes off for long time. Followed by this issue, got struck with multiple other keys not working (k, l, < etc...). Had replaced the keyboard. now, i dont see this issue with my laptop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using 'PowerToys', the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> was assigned to its 'Peek' feature by default and overrides others. You just need to disable it!

Comment: Absolutely amazing, this has been bugging me for a few days now and I found the answer 19 minutes after you posted it!

Comment: This helped me was searching on google and came across this post, yes, I am using `Power Toys` and didn't notice that the shortcut `CTRL + SPACE` was assigned to `Peek` Feature, on disabling the feature I am able to use it in `Excel`. Thanks to both the **Original Poster** and the **Solver**

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I was going to buy a new keyboard until I saw this

Comment: Glad you posted about PowerToys and it helped others. For my case, I had to replace the keyboard, Things worked post to it.

Comment: I too want to thank you for this answer